# How to pass multiple parameters defined in the MVC Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I have a method for MVC, something like this following:

```
public ActionResult MVCMethod(string a,string b)
{……}
```

How to pass the two parameters in a content? Or Must I define my function like this following and then use one content to pass for a, and from uri for b?

```
 public ActionResult MVCMethod([FromBody]string a,string b)
    {……}
```

Another question is——Is MVC not supporting overload functions with the same method? something like this following:

```
public ActionResult MethodTest(string a,string b){……}
public ActionResult MethodTest(string a){……}
public ActionResult MethodTest(string a,string b,string c){……}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `How to pass the two parameters in a content?`

Comment: Use mvc attribute routing or define your routes appropriately or in case of ajax request make sure to match parameter name. In get request use [FromUri] and in post request use [FromBody]

Comment: @Reddy：I mean if I wanna pass two values to the two parameters defined in the function, and I don't wanna use something like "a.aspx?a=1" ( I don't wanna pass parameters directly through the url). Both of the string parameters should be assigned through body content, should that be OK?

Comment: @J-D：Please see "@Reddy" comment. That's what I want to do.

Comment: you could use model in the action attribute

Comment: Are you posting a from with data to controller, Or are you executing a simple call, like anchor tag click etc

Comment: I mean: How can pass multiple seperated parameters with simple types through a form? Is that possible?